# Why can Python not discover the Boost-Pretty-Printer module here?

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to get [Boost-Pretty-Printer](https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer) working, but GDB is rejecting the documented installation procedure (with the same error shown in the testcase below).

I tried the Python script in isolation and, as I'm not a Pythonista I can't see why the import fails:

```
[root@localhost daemon]# ls -l ~/Boost-Pretty-Printer/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  5 16:00 boost
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  5 16:00 examples
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3197 Mar  5 16:00 README.org
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  989 Mar  5 16:00 supported.txt
[root@localhost daemon]# ls -l ~/Boost-Pretty-Printer/boost
total 48
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 Mar  5 16:00 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 48582 Mar  5 16:00 printers.py
[root@localhost daemon]# cat ~/.gdbinit
#python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '~/Boost-Pretty-Printer')
from boost.printers import register_printer_gen
register_printer_gen(None)
end

[root@localhost daemon]# python ~/.gdbinit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.gdbinit", line 4, in <module>
    from boost.printers import register_printer_gen
ImportError: No module named boost.printers
```

Why can the module not be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic of `~` is a shell feature that's not available here, so you have to write out the path in full.

In this case:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/root/Boost-Pretty-Printer')
```

Or, more flexibly, using [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to replace `~` with the user's home directory:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser('~/Boost-Pretty-Printer'))
```

Comment: You could also use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to replace `~` with the user's home directory: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser('~/Boost-Pretty-Printer'))`.